# Why doesn't scala.util.Try implement GenTraversableOnce?

Tags: scala, monads, implicit-conversion

Thanks to the latest offering from Martin Odersky on Coursera, I have begun playing with `scala.util.Try`.  However, I was surprised to find that it doesn't necessarily play well with the collection monads because it doesn't implement `scala.collection.GetTraversableOnce`.

This could come in handy.  For instance, you could convert a list of strings to integers while throwing out the bad ones like this:

```
def ints(strs:List[String]):List[Int] = strs.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt))
```

The workaround is simple.  Just convert the `Try` to an `Option` and let its implicit conversion work for us:

```
def ints(strs:List[String]):List[Int] = strs.flatMap(s => Try(s.toInt).toOption)
```

Seems to me that `Try` would either implement `GenTraversableOnce` or have its own implicit conversion.  Can anyone explain why it doesn't?  Is it simply the fact `Try` isn't actually a monad?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never particularly liked that idiom for `Option` (although I use it and it's never bitten me). Having an explicit [`catMaybes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html) seems nicer than mixing up monads via an implicit conversion.

Comment: More to the point: `Option` can be viewed pretty naturally as a collection with a maximum length of one. Viewing `Try` in the same way means ignoring part of its semantics. Sometimes it makes sense to do this (which is why `toOption` exists), but you don't want it to happen unexpectedly.

Comment: @TravisBrown I'm still green when it comes to functional programming, with Scala being my only language thus far. That being said, I didn't recognize any difference between the Scala Option and the Haskell Maybe. Is there a subtle difference that I'm missing?

Comment: It's the difference between `(0 to 9).flatMap(Some(_))` (which compiles only because of the implicit conversion you mention) and the equivalent `[0..9] >>= Just` (which doesn't compile).

Comment: @TravisBrown I see your point in your second comment. Perhaps the reason is that squelching the `Failure` cases should be explicit.

Comment: Monad goal is incapsulation of side effect and it need to provide 2 natural transformation (operation): lift to monad and join monads. So first - Try { ... } and second - MA flatMap { A => MB }. Imho 'Try' is monad with all monadic attributes.

Comment: @Yury: The goal of monads is much more general than the encapsulation of side effects, and it's at least possible to argue that `Try` is not monadic (although exactly what that means in the context of a language like Scala isn't always clear).

Comment: @TravisBrown put your comments regarding the semantic difference between a collection and a Try as an answer and I'll close this question.

Comment: A Try obeys the [Monad laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Monad_laws), so in my opinion it is a monad. However, the original question is why it doesn't extend GenTraversableOnce, which is more a question of whether it is a collection than whether it is a monad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Monad, but in my opinion, it's really not a collection in the way you're trying to use it. FlatMap is not for translating between *different* monads (`M[A]=>M[B]`, yes, but not `M[A]=>N[B]` or even `M[A]=>N[A]`). It feels more like you want something like:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success}

def ints2(strs: List[String]): List[Int] =
  strs.map { s => Try(s.toInt) }.collect { case Success(n) => n }
```

or

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def ints3(strs: List[String]): List[Int] = strs.flatMap { s =>
    Try(s.toInt) match {
        case Success(n) => List(n)
        case Failure(ex) => List.empty
    }
}
```

=>

```
scala> ints2(List("1","2","a","3"))
res8: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```